# How can I copy a playlist from my iPod to iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipod, playlist

I have some playlists which exist on my iPod only; I lost them in iTunes the last time I did a backup.  How can I get these (non-smart) playlists out of the iPod, and restore them to iTunes?

I have a 2nd gen iPod Nano, which I connect via USB to iTunes (v10.6.0.40) on a Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several applications for doing this:

### [Yamipod](http://www.yamipod.com/main/modules/home/)

Yamipod is a freeware application that works on Windows, OS X, and Linux. It has a simple interface and looks very easy to use. There is a document on how to transfer songs from your iPod to your computer [here.](http://www.yamipod.com/main/modules/docs/help/copyfromipod.php) It is also an iPod manager and an alternative to using iTunes.

[image: Yamipod]

### [Transferpod](http://www.transferpod.com/)

[image: Transferpod logo]
Transferpod is avaiable for both Windows and OS X. However, it is *not* free. It supports the iPod shuffle, the iPod mini, the iPod nano, the iPod classic, the iPod with video, the iPod touch, and the iPhone.

Key features:

> - iPod to computer transfer
> - Manage iPod playlists in an easy way
> - Organize entire iPod music/video for your convenience
> - Browse iPod file information in detail
> - Quick search your music and video file on iPod

### [iPod2iTunes](http://www.theboysdownunder.com/ipod2itunes/)

iPod2iTunes is for Windows. It also is *not* free.
[image: iPod2iTunes]

Features include:

> - Connect multiple iPods.
> - Drag and Drop Songs, Playlists or Video   back to iTunes.
> - Move entire genres, albums and artists.
> - Keeps your playlists intact.
> - Enhanced searching and grouping of songs.
> - Find duplicate songs within iTunes and remove them quickly.
> - Optimizes iPod storage space.
> - Supports [Virtual iPods.](http://www.theboysdownunder.com/vpod/)
> - Support for the latest 6th generation iPods.   (excluding iPod
>   Touch/iPhone)

Comment: Wow!  Is there no way to do this in iTunes?

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately, iTunes is pretty restricting.